# Is this a bug in os or can someone explain to me what's going on?

Tags: python, operating-system

```
>>> os.path.realpath("C:")
'C:\\PythonApp'
>>> os.path.realpath("E:")
'E:\\'
```

My current directory is `C:\PythonApp`. It seems `os` defaults to the current directory if I give it an unknown path name for something like `os.listdir` so why does it work for E and not C?

Comment: What’s the quote? If you think you’ve found a bug in the OS, 99.9% of the time you haven’t, you should check your code again; and the other 0.1% of the time you still haven’t, you still need to check your code again.

Comment: It's the same behavior as when you you type `dir C:` or `dir E:` at the windows command line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare what you get with:

```
 os.path.realpath("C:\\")
```

Windows saves a "current directory" for each drive, and `C:` (*without* the slash) refers to that, not the root of the drive.
The python docs for `os.path.join` mention this:

> Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.